# Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data on jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

This seems to be a common "problem" but I could not find a solution somewhere else, so I'm asking here.

I get this with ajax from a flask app, which seems to be valid JSON (at least to me).

[image: error]

Any hints at what's wrong?

```js
$('.categoryCheckbox').click(function(id) {
  $('.courseFilters').empty();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'getCategoryCourse/' + id,
    success: function(response) {
      var respons = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
      console.log(respons);
      if (respons.length == 0) {
        $('.courseFilters').append('هیچ رکوردی ثبت نشده است');
      } else {
        respons.forEach(element => [
          $('.courseFilters').append(`<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="${asset('storage/'.element.image)}" class="card-img-top" alt="${element.title}">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">${element.title}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer p-0">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center ps-3">${element.body}</div>
          <div>
            <a href="${element.path()}">
              <span class="bg-info d-inline-block p-2"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-2x"></i></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`)
        ]);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Please post an example of the response. If the ajax works, please remove all but the success function in the snippet I made you

Comment: Text copied from this thread https://forum.jquery.com/topic/json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-2-of-the-json-data

Answer (score 3):

there is a bug in the code

```
var respons = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Remove this line, you should not  parse the result, it returns  javascript object already

and for the future, it is better to use this syntax, when you really need to parse something

```
JSON.parse(....)
```