# Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have been reading some of the other questions here but I can't find one that fully explains how I should fix it. I am new to JSON and don't fully understand it all.

I have to search price range(min_price & max_price) from two columns(regular_price & sale_price) but unable to get values from both columns.

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: {{ $min_price }},
            max: {{ $max_price }},
            values: [ 0, {{ $max_price }} ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                var amount = $( "#amount" ).val( " $ " + ui.values[ 0 ] + " -  $ " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '{{ route('priceFilter') }}',
                    data: 'amount',
                    success: function (response) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(response);
                        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                            console.log(element);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( " $ " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " -  $ " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
</script>
```

I click on the range I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: so, your `amount` variable, contains a jquery collection, not the value of an input. furthermore... When you tried to pass it to your data property, you instead just passed the string 'amount'. But even if you passed the variable, the variable doesn't contain a value that would make sense in your data property. The error you receive is due to you trying to parse something that isn't json as json.

Comment: Why do you indicate that you expect "html" back from the server, and then attempt to json.parse it?

Comment: with dataType: "json", the json.parse isn't necessary.

Comment: I mean delete this `var data = JSON.parse (response);`?

Answer (score 1):

This is:

- a data type problem or
- a formatting error or
- a null value of a variable.

My track:

- My user did not have write rights.
- I had to write a decimal in SQL backend but the code had concatenated quotes around it so that `1.00` became a string `'1.00'`.
- I had to replace any null values of a variable with an empty string `''` right at the start of a bigger function so that the checks against `''` worked.

In your case, you used a string value instead of a an integer for the amount. Perhaps, there are other values in your code that lead to such an error. It is not only such data type error, but also the formatting. For example, the min_price and max_price might come as decimal to the front-end, but are integer in the back-end?

There is a wide range of such data type errors at
[SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse). The link is the official help for your error, shown in the debugger of the browser (`Ctrl+Shift+C` or `F12` --> Debugger):

[image]

[image]

Check the whole guide.

---

On top of this, not solving the error, here is another small thing that I read in the comments and in another answer. Without having tested it, and I do not know anything about it. As in the answer to [Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data on jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70915167/11154841), and as said in the comment:

> with dataType: "json", the json.parse isn't necessary.

Change

```js
                    success: function (response) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(response);
                        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                            console.log(element);
                        });
                    }
```

to

```js
                    success: function (response) {
                        $.each(response, function (index, element) {
                            console.log(element);
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

that was your line:

```
data: 'amount',
```

you should may change it to this format:

```
 $.ajax({
         url: 'something.php',
         data: {amount: amount},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.error) {
                       //your code
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I changed this like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65KJ1.png . But I get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOjqd.png